# Fraction simplification numerator unclear

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions

I'm watching the first MIT OCW 18.01 lecture. In this lecture, the lecturer gives a treatment of finding the derivative for $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$. He presents this interstitial step $$\frac{\Delta f}{\Delta x} = \frac{\frac{1}{x_0+\Delta x} - \frac{1}{x_0}}{\Delta x}$$ and simplifies it to $$\frac{\Delta f}{\Delta x} = \frac{1}{\Delta x}\left(\frac{x_0 - \left(x_0 + \Delta x\right)}{\left(x_0 + \Delta x\right)x_0}\right)$$.

He explains the simplification as factoring out the $\frac{1}{\Delta x}$ from the denominator and then multiplying the resulting denominators $x_0 + \Delta x$ and $x_0$ to obtain the denominator $\frac{x_0 - \left(x_0 + \Delta x\right)}{\left(x_0 + \Delta x\right)x_0}$ and then "figuring out what the numerator had to be". It's not clear to me how the numerator in this case would be anything other than $-1$; indeed, after some simplification, he ends up with $\frac{\Delta f}{\Delta x} = \frac{-1}{x^2}$.

What are the steps involved in simplifying the numerator in this expression, and what am I missing here? To try to be more clear, I understand that ultimately the numerator cancels to be $-1$. I understand the power rule and how to use it to short-circuit round the step by step procedure. What I am not clear on is how, in the *intermediate* step, the numerator is an expression involving $x_0$ and $\Delta x$. How did this come up? Where does it come from?

Comment: The result should be $-\frac{1}{x^2}$

Comment: The [derivative of $x^n$ is $nx^{n-1}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative#Rules_for_basic_functions). Thus the derivetive of $\dfrac 1 x=x^{-1}$ must be: $(-1)x^{-2}=-  \dfrac {1}{x^2}$.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, Peter, you are quite right. I have amended the question to show that. Mauro, I understand the power rule, what I'm asking about, specifically, is the $x_0 - \left(x_0 + \Delta x\right)$ numerator in the intermediate step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not completely clear on what you are asking, but the numerator $x_0-(x_0+\Delta x)$ comes from this:
$$\frac{1}{x_0+\Delta x} - \frac{1}{x_0}=\frac{x_0}{x_0(x_0+\Delta x)}-\frac{x_0+\Delta x}{x_0(x_0+\Delta x)}=\frac{x_0-(x_0+\Delta x)}{x_0(x_0+\Delta x)}$$

Comment: What I am asking is: how do you obtain the result in the middle? I understand the left side of the left $=$ and the right side of the right $=$ but not the middle.

Comment: @Chris For the fraction $\dfrac{1}{x_0+\Delta x}$, multiply both the numerator and denominator by $x_0$. We get $\dfrac{x_0}{x_0(x_0+\Delta x)}$, which is an equivalent fraction. Similar for the other fraction.

Comment: OH. Oh. Right. Of course. Thank you! I was forgetting that bit. Now it makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

we have $$\frac{1}{\Delta x}\left(\frac{x_0-x_0-\Delta x}{(x_0^2+\Delta xx_0}\right)=\frac{-1}{x_0^2+\Delta x x_0}$$ and for $\Delta x $ tends to $0%$ we get $$\frac{-1}{x_0^2}$$

Comment: I understand how to *get* there, what I'm not sure is why the numerator in the intermediate step can be anything other than $-1$.

Comment: You can cancel the $\Delta x$ and $\frac{-\Delta x}{\Delta x}=-1$

Comment: Maybe I'm not being clear. I apologize! It's late here. I understand that you can cancel that way. What I don't understand is the intermediate step, where the numerator is $x_0 - \left(x_0 + \Delta x\right)$. This is the bit that's confusing me. Why is that not $-1$?

Comment: it is $$x_0-x_0-\Delta x=-\Delta x$$!